# What is index_method in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, index

In the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html), **index_method** is used.

1. Are Index Methods and [Index Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/indexes-types.html) the same thing?
2. Is it possible to create your own index method or are we restricted to the predefined ones ?

I just want to know if it is possible and do people do it. I don't have any reason to create an index method myself

Comment: I didn't want to add this in the question as it is tangential to the question being asked. The reason I want to know this is because i am trying to make an interface for DB management

Comment: In the link, you provided it is used in an EXCLUSION CONSTRAINT. You can find an example of such at  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION

Comment: From [CREATE INDEX page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createindex.html): *PostgreSQL provides the index methods B-tree, hash, GiST, SP-GiST, GIN, and BRIN. Users can also define their own index methods, but that is fairly complicated.*

Comment: [Chapter 61. Index Access Method Interface Definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexam.html) is where you'd start if you want to create a new index type.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Your answer is perfectly correct. Could you post it as an answer so that I can mark it a accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, “index method” and “index type” are the same thing.  The various ways to access table data are called “access methods” in PostgreSQL jargon; see for example the system catalog `pg_am`, where “`am`” stands for “access method”:

```
TABLE pg_am;

  oid  │ amname │      amhandler       │ amtype 
═══════╪════════╪══════════════════════╪════════
     2 │ heap   │ heap_tableam_handler │ t
   403 │ btree  │ bthandler            │ i
   405 │ hash   │ hashhandler          │ i
   783 │ gist   │ gisthandler          │ i
  2742 │ gin    │ ginhandler           │ i
  4000 │ spgist │ spghandler           │ i
  3580 │ brin   │ brinhandler          │ i
 29226 │ bloom  │ blhandler            │ i
(8 rows)
```

The first entry is a “table access method”, and the rest are “index access methods”.

To answer your second question: yes, you can define your own index types. As an example, see the last entry `bloom`. That was added by installing the [bloom extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bloom.html). See the source of that module for how to do that.